# How to convert military time format (e.g. 1305) to hh:mm (e.g. 13:05) in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time

Let's say I have this simple dataframe:

```py
df = {'time': [1305, 850, 6, 1210], 'freq': [10, 15, 20, 25]}
df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns = ['time','freq'])

    time    freq
0   1305    10
1   850     15
2   6       20
3   1210    25
```

Where 1305 means 13:05, 805 means 08:05, 6 means 00:06, 1210 means 12:10 in the 24 hour time format.

Using python, how can I convert the 'time' column to the hh:mm format, as shown above?

Really struggling to solve this so any help is very much appreciated :)

Comment: https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/DateTime.html

Comment: Time has no format, it's a binary value. In this case, it looks like you have *integers* that are treated as if they were *strings* containing a time-of-day. This isn't military time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could convert the column to string, add leading zeros and convert to datetime:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['time'].astype(str).str.zfill(4), format='%H%M').dt.time

0    13:05:00
1    08:50:00
2    00:06:00
3    12:10:00
```

Comment: thanks for your answer :) Do you know how I can remove the seconds and keep it as hh:mm ?

Comment: you can repalce `dt.time` by `dt.strftime('%H:%M')`